# Google Map v2 with Tabhost in Fragment Activity only show gray gridlines

Tags: android, google-maps, android-tabhost, supportmapfragment

```
I am trying google map v2 in tabhost but google map unable to display properly that only showing gray grids, I have extended activity as fragment activity. I tried lots of solution to resolve this problem but nothing helps to me, other things are working properly, even if i open map in separate activity then i can able to do anything with the maps,Please help me to resolve this issue,Thanks in advance.
My code is:

 <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="50" >

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/map"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Below is the method in which i have declered google map, I dont understand why maps are not working in tabhost evend same activity i have extended as fragment activity

```
public void declareView() {
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng arg0) {


            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: post the snapshot...!!!

Comment: Hey guys I have resolved my issue by adding below code:
 FragmentManager myFM = getSupportFragmentManager();

  SupportMapFragment myMAPF = (SupportMapFragment) myFM
    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
  myMAPF.onResume();

  mMap = myMAPF.getMap();

  mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
  mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you haven't fetched a Google Maps API key. Failing to do so prevents the map from being displayed. For instructions on how to get one visit this page:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/#apikey

Comment: Alright. Do you have any issues showing up in your Logcat?

Comment: No, Nothing is on Logcat

Answer (score 0):

are you sure the map is shown up in the normal fragment ?

I mean did you try to show map without the tabhost first ? to make sure that the map is working fine ?